# Route53 wildcard issue

Tags: dns, webserver, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS Route53 and I got stuck in a problem and I cant really understand the issue.

I have created one hosted zone in Route53. Under that I have created some record sets. I have two private servers. Say one with ip 192.168.1.2 and the other 192.168.1.3. The first server **.2** hosts various number of sites and the second one not as much.

So I wanted to to set the record set for the first server with a wildcard. I set something like

```
*.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.2
a.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.3
b.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.3
c.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.3
d.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.3
```

As you can see I am ok to specify sub domains pointing to **.3** but for **.2** I need to set wildcard.
Everything works fine if specify the sub domain and point it to **.2** but wildcard fails.

```
e.tp.example.com    A    192.168.1.2 //this works fine
```

Is this possible to do or am I missing out something? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: For what it's worth, this configuration should work as expected.  Are you verifying Route53 behavior using `dig`?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Yes i got this working. You can specify wildcards in AWS.

Comment: It turned out that it was the DNS cache on our in house DNS Server.